# Fastest Method to read many files line by line in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pathlib

I have a conceptual question. I am new to Python and I am looking to do task that involves processing bigger log files. Some of these can get up to 5 and 6GB

I need to parse through many files in a location. These are text files.

I know of the with open() method, and recently just ran into pathlib. So I need to not only read the file line by line to extract values to upload into a DB, i also need to get file properties that Pathlib gives you and upload them as well.

Is it faster to use with open and underneath it, call a path object from which to read files... something like this:

```
for filename in glob('**/*.*', recursive=False):
    fpath = Path(filename)
    with open(filename, 'rb', buffering=102400) as logfile:
        for line in logfile:
            #regex operation
            print(line)
```

Or would it be better to use Pathlib:

```
with Path("src/module.py") as f:
    contents = open(f, "r")
    for line in contents:
        #regex operation
        print(line)
```

Also since I've never used Pathlib to open files for reading. When it comes to this: `Path.open(mode=’r’, buffering=-1, encoding=None, errors=None, newline=None)`

What does newline and errors mean? I assume buffering here is the same as buffering in the with open function?

I also saw this contraption that uses with open in conjuction with Path object though how it works, I have no idea:

```
path = Path('.editorconfig')
with open(path, mode='wt') as config:
    config.write('# config goes here')
```

Comment: no one can answer this question for you without having access to your data and database. i recommend installing ipython/jupyter and using the `%timeit` magic command on a small subset of your data

Comment: @PaulH What about in general? What's typically faster? Or is with open() the same as Path.open()

Comment: I have no idea. I would use the `%timeit` magic to find out.

Comment: You'll find `grep` to be a good fit for matching lines of files to regular expressions, and being implemented in c by professionals,   it's blazing fast.  Reimplement in python if it strikes your fancy,  but think of it as an academic pursuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pathlib` is intended to be a more elegant solution to interacting with the file system, but it's not necessary. It'll add a small amount of fixed overhead (since it wraps other lower level APIs), but shouldn't change how performance scales in any meaningful way.

Since, as noted, `pathlib` is largely a wrapper around lower level APIs, you should know `Path.open` is implemented in terms of `open`, and the arguments all mean the same thing for both; reading [the docs for the built-in `open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) will describe the arguments.

As for the last bit of your question (passing a `Path` object to the built-in `open`), that works because most file-related APIs were updated to support any object that implements [the `os.PathLike` ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=path%20like#os.PathLike).

Comment: SO I can just use Path.open() and no noticeable overhead will happen then?

Comment: @edo101: Yeah, it has a trivial amount of fixed overhead to pass through the layers of `pathlib` wrapping, but it's noise relative to the costs of disk I/O in general; wasting a few microseconds for an operation that takes milliseconds is meaningless.

Comment: ended up using 'with open(path obj, 'rb')' instead of Path.open(). Slightly faster I'd think since I am nout using the Path wrapper no?

Comment: @edo101: It's meaningless either way; the `Path` object wrapper is still invoked there, but all it has to do is convert itself to a string via the `PathLike` ABC's interface. In both cases, it's a trivial amount of overhead paid when you actually open the file, but the resulting file object is the same, with the same performance.

Comment: Should I try to not use Pathlib then? Or am I being paranoid about potential performance hits that Pathlib would introduce?

Comment: @edo101: You're being paranoid. Like I said, disk I/O is multiple orders of magnitude slower than all of the overhead `pathlib` introduces. If it takes 1 ms to open a file normally, and 1.003 ms to open it because you used `pathlib` (invented numbers, but roughly in the right ballpark), do you really care about the 0.003 ms enough to make it worth writing code that takes you even one more minute to write and verify, and then a second or so of delay when rereading it for maintenance later? Microoptimizations for code speed that cost development/maintenance time aren't worth it 99+% of the time.